# ASP.NET Routing Regex to match specific pattern

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for ASP.NET MapPageRoute that matches a specific type of path.

I do not want to match anything with a file extension so I used this regex ^[^.]*$ which worked fine except it also picked up if the default document was requested. I do not want it to pick up the default document so I have been trying to change it to require at least one character. I tried adding .{1,} or .+ to the beginning of the working regex but it stopped working alltogether.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("content", "{*contentpath}", "~/Content.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { }, new RouteValueDictionary { { "contentpath", @"^[^.]*$" } });
```

How can I change my regex to accomplish this?

Unfortunately my brain does not seem capable of learning regular expressions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change your `*` quantifier to `+`. `*` matches zero or more times, whereas `+` matches one or more. So, what you are asking for is this:

```
^[^.]+$
```

The regex is accomplishing this: "At the beginning of the string, match all characters that are not `.`, at least one time, up to the end of the string."

Answer (score 0):

`^[^.]+$`

zero is to * as one is to +